# Does CGImage support 16 bits per channel?

Tags: quartz-2d, cgimage, color-depth, bit-depth

[bitsPerComponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454980-bitspercomponent) says it's at most 8, but a couple of Stack Overflow questions [imply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974484/help-please-with-cgbitmapcontext-and-16-bit-images) 16 is [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998969/64-bit-rgba-uiimage-cgbitmapinfo-for-64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the necessary information in “Supported Pixel Formats“ in the “Graphics Contexts“ chapter of “Quartz 2D Programming Guide“ below even it is archived documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html

The below figure is taken from the above url.

[image: Supported Pixel Formats by Apple]

Note that “bpp“ is specified as “bits per pixel“ and “bcp“ is “bits per component“. As given in above table, it seems that only Mac OS (>=10.X versions) supports 16 bcp, not iOS.